# Why is the 1x1 convolution and linear results I used in pytorch inconsistent

Tags: cnn, convolutional-neural-network, pytorch

```py
import torch 
import torch.nn as nn

def conv(inputs , weights , bias):
    inputs = inputs.permute(0,2,1)
    conv = nn.Conv1d(10,64,1)
    conv.weight.data = weights
    conv.bias.data = bias
    bn = nn.BatchNorm1d(64)

    return bn(conv(inputs)).permute(0,2,1)

def fc(inputs , weights , bias):
    fc = nn.Linear(10,64)
    fc.weight.data = weights.reshape(64,10)
    fc.bias.data = bias
    bn = nn.BatchNorm1d(64)
    return bn(fc(inputs).permute(0,2,1)).permute(0,2,1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    inputs = torch.randn(12000,32,10)
    weights = torch.randn(64,10,1)
    bias = torch.randn(64)
    conv_outputs = conv(inputs , weights , bias )
    fc_outputs = fc(inputs , weights , bias )
    print((conv_outputs - fc_outputs).sum())
    print((conv_outputs -conv(inputs , weights , bias)).sum())
```

The result is like this

```
tensor(0.3120, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)
tensor(0., grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)
```